# Collection Next Element

Tags: c#, collections, backgroundworker

I have a method to download a picture, a list of pictures to be downloaded, and multiple background workers.

The way I have it worked out now, I divide my collection in two, and loop through with each background worker.

My question is, how can I have 2 or more background workers pulling from the same collection, without them stepping on each other.

```
List<string> Urls = new List<string>(Pretend I Added 50 URL'S);
List<string> Urls1 = new List<string>();
List<string> Urls1 = new List<string>();

Urls1.Add(Urls.GetRange(0,25);
Url2.Add(Urls.GetRange(26,50);

BackgroundWorker bwImageDownload1 = new BackgroundWorker();

        bwImageDownload1.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(string item in Urls1.Items)
            {
              DownloadPicture(item);
            }
        };


        bwImageDownload1.RunWorkerAsync();

BackgroundWorker bwImageDownload2 = new BackgroundWorker();

        bwImageDownload2.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(string item in Urls2.Items)
            {
              DownloadPicture(item);
            }
        };


        bwImageDownload2.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: What framework version are you using

Comment: Just throwing out an idea, but you could have a variable `index`, and a method that gets the index and increments it so the other background worker gets the next one and so on. You can use the Lock statement for this.

Comment: @Sievajet sorry, .net 4.0

Comment: There is no reason to use `BackgroundWorker` in .Net 4.0. Just use TPL. Also, if you make your `DownloadPicture` asynchronous, then you don't need threads at all to call them.

Comment: I knew it was an xy problem, I just wasn't sure what x even was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pattern: having `n` work items that need to be processed by `k` worker, concurrently. A [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) data structure works well for this.

There are multiple kinds of queues that you could work with (for example, for larger, more regular workloads, you might consider having a separate [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) process), but for your example it would likely suffice to just use an in-memory queue like the [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> urlQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
// ... fill it with the URLs ...

// Then, in your workers...
string url;
while (urlQueue.TryDequeue(out url)) {
    DownloadPicture(url);
}
```

The `ConcurrentQueue` is thread-safe, so it will make sure that the two workers don't step on each other when attempting to dequeue from the URL queue.

---

In addition, like @SriramSakthivel mentioned, in .NET 4 one can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.100).aspx) for these kinds of async operations. In fact, the entirety of your example could be reduced to a single call to `Parallel.ForEach(urlList, url => DownloadPicture(url));` (although you would have less control over the operation; for more control, you could work with `Task`s directly).

Comment: ive never read queue that many times in one minute. it makes me realize what a strange word it is. its amazing how long I have used .net and still have awesome classes I do not know exist. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice, I like this solution!